# My video files keep turning into binary files in transfer to my WD external HD

Tags: external-hdd, dropbox

I'm trying to transfer my videos to an external hard drive and to drop box. My HD is a Western Digital 3 TB one I use as a cloud drive to stream on the go and to my smart TV. They keep changing format.

I need them to retain their video formats so devices like my phone, TV and others can still play them.

How can I stop them from changing? How can I transfer them properly to my HD and Dropbox?

I am not allowed to post pictures yet, so I can't show you what it looks like lol.

Comment: What do you mean by "binary files"?

Comment: It's what it says under properties.

Comment: And what is the problem? Can you watch these videos? Did you try to open them by some media player like VLC?

Comment: They become un readable from their new locations. They're not even considered media files. VLC won't even try to open it. In its original location works perfectly fine though.

Comment: Type: Binary (application/octet-stream)      that's what it says under properties instead of MP4 or AVI like they used to be.

Comment: Did you try to open these files using VLC? Not just double-click files. Right-click it and "open with" some media player.

Comment: VLC will play it from my laptop but I used the HD to stream to my SMART TV at home and my phone when I'm on the go.

Comment: Your question is not clear. VLC plays the file, so there is no problem. You can change association by setting e.g. VLC as default application to open this type of files. What, how do you stream, what does this mean is unclear. Please [edit] your question and explain what really is a problem.

Comment: Okay sorry. My WD external is used as a cloud drive. My phone, TV and many other devices are linked to it whenever I have Internet. My laptop is used for office and downloading only. I never watch media on it. So my issue is that I need it to stay the same type after putting it in my external so I can use it on other devices that done support awesome players like VLC.

Comment: How do you copy files?

Comment: Copy/paste and move to. Drag and drop kinda stuff.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Yeah. Got that now lol. Bit of a noob sometimes lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the extension has changed, then change it back to what it was originally. See if it plays then.

Comment: Thanks. Got it sorted. You were right and it was trying to use apple protocols for some godless reason.